# ORACLE SPATIAL ERROR

Tags: sql, oracle, geospatial, geoserver, spatial-query

1. I created `all_incidents_uni` view, columns `id`, and `ora_geometry`
2. I created index for view in `user_sdo_geom_metadata`
3. When I create a layer in `geoserver` and open it layer clic to return this error

> Rendering process failed java.io.IOExceptionORA-13226: interface not supported without a spatial index ORA-06512:at "MDSYS.MD", 
>       line 1723 ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.MDERR", 
>       line 8 ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.SDO_3GL", 
>       line 1263

Answer (score 0):

Adding the information in `user_sdo_geom_metadata` does not create an index, merely registers information about a geometry nature and spatial reference system.

I have never tried to build a spatial index on top of a dynamically created value in Oracle, but drawing a parallel with PostGIS, it seems a functional index would be required.

Apparently it is possible to create one in Oracle too, see this page:
http://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000011694